# C# Winforms getting stuck and go to "Not responding" state

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a Winforms C#.net application.

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
private bool cancelQueryWaitRequested = false;

public FormMain()
{
        InitializeComponent();
}

private async void btnQueueStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QueryFinishedWait();
}

private int QueryFinishedWait()
{
        int i = 1;
        reQueueUIStart();
        groupWaitQueue.Visible = true;
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            lblQueueWaitSeconds.Text = (20 - i).ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            if (cancelQueryWaitRequested)
                break;
        }
        groupWaitQueue.Visible = false;
        reQueueUIStop();
        return i;
    }
 }
```

When I execute this, the application goes "Not responding" and I can see the Processor usage goes very high.

But when I run the same loop within `btnQueueStart_Click` it works properly.

I know I am doing something wrong, still can't figure what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a countdown in a loop and sleeping for a second on each iteration.  Have a look at the Timer class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I was using Thread.Sleep for demo, but i was using await Task.Delay(1000); actually function. You're Correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I run the same loop within btnQueueStart_Click it works properly.

That's because the event handler is async, but you destroy that when calling your method.

```
private async void btnQueueStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //QueryFinishedWait();
    await QueryFinishedWait();
}

async private Task<int> QueryFinishedWait()
{
    ... // await something
}
```

But it seems you're missng another piece of the async puzzle. And please note that waiting with `Sleep()` is not recommended.